# Complete setup of Exim4 as SMTP to reach most inboxes as possible (correct configuration)

Tags: debian, email, smtp, exim

I have over the last days tried to setup Exim4 to handle all mails sent from a web application.

It seems to be working, but I haven't found out how to hardcode the hostname which will be sent with EHLO? (I don't want to set `/etc/hostname`)

Have found the variable `MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME` mentioned in the config but havn't found a way to set it. Is this variable the simplest way to set the hostname or is there a better way to do it?

Below is the complete install/config.. Am I missing something?

`Exim version 4.92`
`Debian Buster 10`

## Install

```
apt-get install exim4-daemon-light
```

## Configure Exim4

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config

Type:           internet site
FQDN:           smtp.mydomain.com
SMTP listener:      (empty)
Mail destinations:  (empty)
Domain relay:       (empty)
Machine relay:      (empty)
DNS queries minimal:    No
Delivery method:    Maildir
Split conf files:   No
```

## Enable TLS and generate certs

```
printf "MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = true\n" >> /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros
/usr/share/doc/exim4-base/examples/exim-gencert
```

## check reverse DNS (IP -> smtp.mydomain.com)

https://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx

## Get IPv6

```
ip -6 addr | grep inet6 | awk -F '[ \t]+|/' '{print $3}' | grep -v ^::1 | grep -v ^fe80
```

## /etc/hosts

```
[ipv4]  smtp.mydomain.com
[ipv6]  smtp.mydomain.com
```

## uncomment in '/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template'

```
# plain_server:
# driver = plaintext
# public_name = PLAIN
# server_condition = "${if crypteq{$3}{${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$2}lsearch{CON$
# server_set_id = $2
# server_prompts = :
# .ifndef AUTH_SERVER_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
# server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_cipher}{}{}{*}}
# .endif
```

## add user/pass -> '/etc/exim4/passwd'

```
/usr/share/doc/exim4-base/examples/exim-adduser
```

## DKIM/SPF

I have setup DKIM keys on the server and DKIM/SPF on DNS and both works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA = whatever.you.want` in `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros`. It's supported by the Debian package since 4.69-10. From `/usr/share/doc/exim4/changelog.Debian.gz`:

> - Allow setting outgoing smtp helo/ehlo by setting
>     REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA macro directly. Previously this was just supposed
>     to be used as a helper macro for REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_FROM_DNS.
>     REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_FROM_DNS overrides a manual REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA data
>     setting. Closes: [#514113](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=514113)

This macro is used by the Debian configuration template to populate the `helo_data` [SMTP transport option](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_smtp_transport.html#SECID146).